# Where is SKNode Inspector on Xcode 6?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I'm running Xcode 6 beta 6, and when I go to View -> Utilities, I do not see SKNode Inspector. Was it moved to another place?

Answer (score 0):

Found it; click on `GameScene.sks` and the click on the cube in the tools header on the right panel.